# Subgroup of free product of cyclic group is still a free product of cyclic groups?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I learnt that subgroup of free group is still a free group.

How far can we generalize this?

In particular, is a subgroup of free product of cyclic groups, eg.
$$\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\dots *\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}*\dots *\mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$$
still a free product of cyclic groups?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, by the Kurosh Subgroup Theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Kurosh Subgroup theorem. Can someone familiar with the theorem point out why it is a consequence? I do not really understand Wikipedia's article on Kurosh Subgroup Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem

Comment: The Kurosh subgroup theorem says that a subgroup of a free product is equal to the free product of a free group and conjugates of subgroups of the free factors. A free group is a free product of the cyclic groups generated by its free generators, and subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic.